# Set alpha for the Button in a Dialog

Tags: android, alpha, android-alertdialog, android-button

I need to set the alpha on CustomAlertDialog `Button`. I tried this:

```
AlertDialog userdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                    .create();
    userdialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton) {
                     // Snippet: Do sth.
            return;
            }
        });

userdialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).getBackground().setAlpha(100);
```

But I get this error:

```
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ttet.tsquare.pure/com.ttet.tsquare.pure.Map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at com.ttet.tsquare.pure.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:160)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at com.ttet.tsquare.pure.Map.onCreate(Map.java:63)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-18 08:57:43.831: E/AndroidRuntime(4955):

... 11 more
```

What wrong? What should I do?

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` in the `show` method from the `Dialog` class at line 160.

Comment: I know that, But how i refer to the button without getting this exception. that's the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getButton` method will return `null` if the `Button` can't be found in the dialog or the method `show()` wasn't called prior to its call.
In order to avoid the `NullPointerException` call `getButton` and set the alpha **after** you call `show()` on the `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , these make me understand more step about alert dialog.

Comment: and sorry for my english grammar, It's not my native.

Comment: I have one more question. I successful set button alpha and make it unclickable but when i do something I have to set alpha again and make it clickable. It work fine but the interface doesn't change at all. how i refresh dialog interface?

Comment: @majorl3oat Did you close the dialog, do something and then start it again(this time with new alpha)?

Comment: Sorry for reply late, If I don't want to dismiss dialog but make it new alpha, Is it possible?

Comment: @majorl3oat Yes it's possible I think, it all depends on how you try to modify the alpha again for that dialog's button.